# How to remove ripple effect from clicking q-list item

Tags: css, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have put together a nice sidebar that has a curved edge and flows nicely into the body of the page however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get rid of the semi transparent ripple effect that goes throw the list item when you click. My item turns white so having that semi transparent click event inside my nice white active class effect kills it for me. I want my own style of the item becoming active to be the only effect.

```
    <template>
    <q-drawer show-if-above v-model="leftDrawerOpen" :width="drawerWidth" side="left" behavior="desktop">
      <div class="window-height bg-black text-white">
        <div class="q-py-xl">
          
        </div>
        <div class="q-py-xl">
          <q-list class="curved-parent-ul">
            <q-item v-for="(menuItem, index) in primaryMenuArr" :key="index" class="curved-child-li"
              :active="activeMenuItem === menuItem.name"
              @click="activeMenuItem = menuItem.name"
              active-class="active"
              clickable
              manual-focus>
              <q-icon size="sm" :name="menuItem.icon" class="absolute-center" />
            </q-item>
          </q-list>
        </div>
      </div>
    </q-drawer>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

  import { ref } from 'vue'

  const leftDrawerOpen: Ref<boolean> = ref(true)
  const drawerWidth: Ref<number> = ref(100)
  const activeMenuItem: Ref<string> = ref('Home')

  interface menuArr {
    name: string;
    ariaLabel: string;
    icon: string;
    link: string;
    }
  const primaryMenuArr: menuArr[ ] = [
    { name: 'Home', ariaLabel: 'Home', icon: 's_dashboard', link: '#' },
    { name: 'Upload', ariaLabel: 'Upload', icon: 's_drive_folder_upload', link: '#' },
    { name: 'Management', ariaLabel: 'Management', icon: 's_work', link: '#' },
    ]
</script>
<style scoped>
.curved-parent-ul {
  background: #000000;
  padding: 20px 0 10px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;

}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li.active:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:-30px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 #fff;
}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li.active:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height:30px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 15px -15px 0 #fff;
}

.curved-parent-ul .curved-child-li.active {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: q-list item is it rippling? i wonder why. in my code q-item, i just remove the v-ripple and rippling is gone.

Comment: Could it be in my css? I only have a few classes to create that curved sidebar look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use no-ripple

```
  <q-item clickable no-ripple>
    <q-item-section avatar>
      <q-icon color="primary" name="bluetooth"></q-icon>
    </q-item-section>

    <q-item-section>Icon as avatar</q-item-section>
  </q-item>
```

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/RweyMdz

Comment: Not sure why but its still doing it even with no-ripple

Comment: yeah no-ripple is not working

Comment: There is no 'no-ripple' directive, and if you remove that from the codepen it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
:v-ripple="false"
```

https://quasar.dev/vue-directives/material-ripples/

The documentation is pretty good.

Comment: Turns out my problem is truly I have a transition effect in my css so it was delaying it showing that slightly gradient as it went away.